# Event listener on HighCharts - android

Tags: android, highcharts

I'm trying to implement event listener on pie chart and some other charts but it is throwing an exception of null pointer.
I tried searching for the solution but didn't find any solution.

I'm using the below code:

```
  chartView = findViewById(R.id.hc);
    options = new HIOptions();
    chartView.setOptions(options);

   HIChart chart = new HIChart();
    chart.setType("pie");
    chart.setPlotShadow(false);
    options.setChart(chart);

    HITitle title = new HITitle();
    title.setText("Best Clients");
    options.setTitle(title);


    HITooltip tooltip = new HITooltip();
    tooltip.setPointFormat("{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>");
    options.setTooltip(tooltip);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();
    HIPlotOptions plotOptions = new HIPlotOptions();
    plotOptions.setPie(new HIPie());
    plotOptions.getPie().setAllowPointSelect(true);
    plotOptions.getPie().setCursor("pointer");
    plotOptions.getPie().setDataLabels(new HIDataLabels());
    plotOptions.getPie().getDataLabels().setEnabled(true);
    plotOptions.getPie().getDataLabels().setFormat("<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %"); ;
    //plotOptions.getPie().getDataLabels().getStyle().setColor("#000000");
    options.setPlotOptions(plotOptions);

    HIPie pie = new HIPie();
    pie.setName("Brands");
    for (int i = 0; i < pieChartData.size(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, Object> object = new HashMap<>();
        object.put("name", tags.get(i));
        object.put("y", pieChartData.get(i));
        data.add(object);
    }

pie.setData(data);
```

//setting event listener here

```
   pie.getPoint().setEvents(new HIEvents());
    
    pie.getPoint().getEvents().setClick(new HIFunction(
            (HIChartContext f) -> {
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Clicked point [ " + f.getProperty("x") + ", " + f.getProperty("y") + " ]",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
            },
            new String[] {"x", "y"}
    ));
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.highsoft.highcharts.Common.HIChartsClasses.HIPoint.setEvents(com.highsoft.highcharts.Common.HIChartsClasses.HIEvents)' on a null object reference
```

Exception occurs on this line:

```
pie.getPoint().setEvents(new HIEvents());
```

Comment: pie.getPoint() is null

Comment: pie.setPoint(new HIPoint());

Comment: After adding the above line, I don't receive any exception now but on click there is no resposne

Comment: I think you get same issue like here:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-android/issues/42
you should check highcharts version you use in your project.

Comment: ok thank you. It was the version issue as you mentioned. I've updated to 8.1.2

Answer (score 0):

```
Need to set the point before getting the point:

pie.setPoint(new HIPoint());
pie.getPoint().setEvents(new HIEvents());
```

Updating to version 8.1.2 solved the listener issue. It now returns the value